# Why is my onChange event different between enzyme shallow and mount components?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a simple React wrapper component around a material-ui `TextField`. I am trying to use enzyme and `simulate` to trigger events on the underlying TextField which are handled in my component, and there's a behavior difference between using `shallow` and using `mount` that I don't understand. When I try to simulate a `keyup` event using either shallow or mount, the event handler runs as I expected.  When I try to simulate a `change` event, nothing seems to happen for the mount case, but it appears to work when using shallow.

In my example test below, I expected to see console output from both of my event handlers, but I see no output for the change event in the case where I use mount.  I know I don't need to use mount here in this specific case, but I'd like to understand this behavior for cases where I do need mount.

How can I properly trigger my change event when using a `mount`ed component?

```
import React from 'react'
import { mount, shallow } from 'enzyme'
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField'

const MyTextField = (props: any) => {
  const handleChange = (e: any) => {
    console.log('in handleChange')
  }
  const handleKeyUp = (e: any) => {
    console.log('in handleKeyUp')
  }
  return <TextField onChange={handleChange} onKeyUp={handleKeyUp} />
}

it('should do something', () => {
  const shallowWrapped = shallow(<MyTextField />)
  shallowWrapped.find(TextField).simulate('keyup', {})  // "in handleKeyUp" output to console
  shallowWrapped.find(TextField).simulate('change', { target: { value: 'test' } }) // "in handleChange" output to console

  const mountWrapped = mount(<MyTextField />)
  mountWrapped.find(TextField).simulate('keyup', {})  // "in handleKeyUp" output to console
  // The below line doesn't seem to work as I expect...
  mountWrapped.find(TextField).simulate('change', { target: { value: 'test' } }) // nothing is output to console
})
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this [Common-Gotchas](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/simulate.html#common-gotchas) from Enzyme, you need to provide a mock event object with properties used in the callback that are not included in the `SyntheticEvent`.

```
it('should do something', () => {
  wrapped = mount(<MyTextField />);
  wrapped.find(TextField).simulate('keyup', {});
  wrapped.find(TextField).simulate('change', { target: { value: 'test' } });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but there's still no callback. I took that docs section to mean that the event callback should still occur, but just that if you needed to use some specific arguments you needed to pass them in.  The keyup event callback seems to be called just fine with simulate and no real args, for example. I edited the question to include the passed-in event args now.